# Efficient way to compare different types of List of Objects

Tags: java, collections, comparator, comparable

```
public class State{

String code;
int occurValue;
int name;

}

public class Equi{
String code;
int occurValue;
int macAddress;

}
```

Having 2 classes of different types.
I'm having a `List<State>` and `List<equi>`. In these lists if code and occurValue is same, I need to move that to different List.
How can I achieve this, googling gave me so many options line Comparable, Comparator. Let me know which is the most efficient way to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "efficient" - lines of code, complexity, runtime? Your question needs to be specific to receive an accurate answer.

Comment: @mabi runtime performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no additional information on the lists, then the most efficient algorithm is to compare each element of the one list with each element of the other:

```
for (State s : stateList) {
    for (equi e : equiList) {
        if (s.code.equals(e.code) && s.occurValue == e.occurValue) {
            // add to another list
        }
    }
}
```

This is O(n * m) (where n is the size of stateList and m is the size of equiList).

If the two lists are sorted, then more efficient algorithms can be used. For example, in pseudocode:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stateList.size(); i++) {
    int j = 0;
    State s = stateList.get(i);
    while (equiList.get(j) is smaller than s) {
        j++;
    }
    equi e = equiList.get(j);
    if (s.code.equals(e.code) && s.occurValue == e.occurValue) {
        // add to another list
    }
}
```

This is O(m + n). Of course, for this to work you will have to write comparison functions (one for comparing a `State` with a `State`, one for comparing an `equi` with an `equi` and one for comparing a `State` with an `equi`).

By the way, Java naming conventions dictate that classes start with a capital letter, so it should be `Equi`, not `equi`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an own defined method to do that, a `Boolean <compare(State state, Equi equi)>` or something like that with the given list items as parameters. And the code:

```
//You have to iterate the method with a for loop for example
//In different situations you need different iterating methods, for example you add 
//1 element to Equi:
//You compare all State element with the new Equi element, but just with that ONE
for (int i =0; i < stateList.size(); i++ {
  flag = compare(stateList.get(i),equiList.get(<indexOfNewElement>); // flag is a boolean value
  if (flag) {
    //moving metod and stuff...
  }
}
//this way you don't make unnecessary steps. It's one example, there are many other situation

Boolean compare(State state, Equi equi) { // You add List elements as parameters
  if (state.getCode().equals(equi.getCode())) { // I prefer to use getters, it depends on your code and preferences
    if (state.getOccurValue() == equi.getOccurValue()) { //same here
      return true; //If returns true, an other method move it.
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else { //if the first ones aren't equal needless to check the second values
    return false;
  }
}
```

This way you can use this method for all comparison, but every time you need to write an iterator. It means more coding, but less runtime. For example if the lists are ordered by `code` in ABC order, you can avoid to compare the "k*" with "a*" using a flag or anything.

Comment: Its a List of object, you need to iterate through each one ?

Comment: Yes, it's the comperating part. You can call it for the whole list in a for loop, parts of the list, or single pairs. This way you don't need to call for the whole lists every time if you don't need to

Comment: This code will *not work*! String comparison using the == operator is a comparison on references and unless they are interned there is no guarantee this will do as intended. Use equals operator instead.

Comment: I didn't knew that there is a `getCode()` method for `List` types. And the usage of the wrapper class `Boolean` has a specific reason?

Comment: Of course there isn't... Are you kidding me? Nor `getOccurValue()`. FYI it's a getter method. And of course again, it's not required to use wrapper, use it when you need to, use `boolean` otherwise.

Comment: And can you tell me, why you write invalid code? This won't help anybody.

Comment: can you explain "invalid"?

Comment: You already noted, that you know that `List` types do not provide methods like `getCode()` or `getOccurValue()`. So either you "forgot" to include the `for` loops which fetches the entities from both provided list to call these methods on them or the argument types are not correct. In the current state, the code won't compile.

Comment: I see. Yes, you are right in that context. But please note that this was just a template. And I wrote a few comments before why didn't implemented the rest. Of course you can't ctrl+c & ctrl+v this method as a solution. I always use my lists with getters, and implement in a specific class. The question was about efficient way, and you can use this method more than once, that's why I didn't wrote for loops and stuff. (for exp.: you add a new element, you don't have to check all the list elements in that list because those element didn't changed)

Comment: It is a good idea not writing the whole code :). In this case it would maybe make sense to write the code as pseudo code, or to add comments like `// implement loops to fetch list elements` or something like that, so the reader know, that this code is not ready to use and he should finalize it, to use it.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the feedback, next time I will pay attention for that. Should I edit the answer updating with these information?

Comment: Sure. It is always good, to improve the answer if possible :).

Answer (score 0):

It highly depends on your definition of "efficient".

If you are not interested in time you can just create **a double foreach loop** and compare each item with each other. **This is brute-force and not time-efficient (as it is O(n^2))**, but saves you a lot of programming time you can spend on something more useful. The same goes with a fairly small number of items (I suggest < 10.000), where time-optimizations usually don't pay of.

If you want it time-efficient you can use some abstract data structure to help you. For example if the "code"-field is unique in each set, **create a HashMap** where the key refers to "code" and the value is the Equi referenct. You can then iterate over your States and query the HashMap for a matching Equi. Ask the returned Equi for its occurValue. You may also introduce a second HashMap with the occurValues as keys. **This should give you O(n) for the comparison part.**

A more **object-oriented approach** you be to create an interface IHasCodeAndOccurValue and let State and Equi implement it. Then you implement equals(IHasCodeAndOccurValue other) methods in both classes. You insert both data sets in a List each and call stateList.retainAll(equiList). This might be **the most elegant approach** and - depending on your chosen List implementation - **can also run in O(n)**.

As you can see, there are several ways of optimizing this code. Without knowing the details it is pure speculation how to proceed.